# javascript call backs( wiki api freecodecamp)

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues with the javascript portion of the "wiki app project" for freecodecamp. I have the wiki API call working correctly when I manually put in the search parameters but I am not able to figure out how to take the user input as the search results.

I need help with running the function for getting the value of the text that is entered first and then run the ajax code to get the value for my input. I am looking for solutions using vanilla javascript.

From what I searched, I think I can do it using call backs but I don't understand how to use it correctly. Below is my code pen.

So far it console logs the value of the text input but doesn't put the value into the ajax url. I assume because all the code runs at once. I had this problem with the weather app as well and did a timeout on it but I know that's not the best way to do it and I am having issues figuring out the correct solution.

https://codepen.io/mcdanije/pen/KRaeqg

```
var input;
function one () {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if( x === 13){
    input = document.getElementById("getResults").value;
    console.log(input);

  }
}  
function results() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function(){
  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = data[1][0];
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = data[2][0];
  document.getElementById("link1").href = data[3][0];
  console.log(data[0]);

}
// testing input // var input = "goku";
var api = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search="
var url = api + input + "&limit=10&origin=*";
xhr.open
 ("GET", url , true)
//orginal url //("GET","https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=goku&limit=10&origin=*", true);
xhr.send(); 
}
```

Comment: Take a few minutes to read through [ask] then edit question so it contains the relevant code in the question itself and only the specific code related explanation.  Questions should be self contained. Demos are great but should only be to help support what actually exists here in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site for a preliminary review of your issue

Answer (score 0):

A callback approach works well for this. "next" is the callback function. Basically you provide your input to the getWikiPages (I renamed your "results" function) function AND a callback function that will be called when the XHR request completes (or errors).

This allows for "asynchronous" responses.

```
var input;
function one () {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if( x === 13){
    input = document.getElementById("getResults").value;
    console.log('onkeydown',input);

    // [1] What will happen if onload never happens?!
    getWikiPages(input,function(data){
      // [1] This will never get called.
      // do something with the data
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = data[1][0];
      document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = data[2][0];
      document.getElementById("link1").href = data[3][0];
    });


  }
}  
function getWikiPages(input,next) {
  var api = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search="
  var url = api + input + "&limit=10&origin=*";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
    console.log('onload',data); 
    next(data); // next() is the callback. 
  }

  xhr.open("GET", url , true)
  xhr.send(); 
  // function ends, but next() will be called when it is really done.
  return 'nothing'; // you could return something here, but normally not.
}
```